Unity 6 Crashing on iOS When Switching Profile in Build Settings
I'm experiencing crashes on iOS when switching profiles in the Build Settings in Unity 6. The application crashes immediately after attempting to switch profiles, and I'm unable to determine the cause.
Unity Version: Unity 6(6000.0.3f1)
Steps to Reproduce:

Open Unity 6 and load the project.
Navigate to Build Settings.
Switch the profile

I'm seeking advice on how to resolve this issue or any pointers on what might be causing the crash.

look in the editor logs?

Thanks for the suggestion. I have looked through the editor logs but didn't find anything that seemed related to the issue.

well if unity crashes there would be an error in there
